# How to run two indices in r

Tags: r, indices

I am struggeling with a VERY simple problem :

I would like to run 2 indices combinations in a loop : i=1,j=1, i=1,j=2,i=1,j=3.....
then switch to i=1,j=2 i=2,j=2 i=3,j=2... and so on until i=n,j=n

I wrote the following code which sadly doesn't work properly :

- I cannot use r functions such as expand.grid etc..

```
a <- function(n) {
  for (i in 1:n)  {
    for (j in 1:n) {
     print(i,j)
    }
  }
}
```

#I expect to get 1,1 1,2 1,3 1,4... 2,1 2,2... but this is not the result.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by saying "I cannot use r functions such as expand.grid". If you say that you don't know how to handle, here is a solution : `apply(expand.grid(1:3,1:3),1,function(x)paste0(x,collapse=","))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work! Just printing with comma only prints the first.

Instead try separating by comma in a string:

```
a <- function(n) {
  for (i in 1:n)  {
    for (j in 1:n) {
     print(paste(i, j, sep=', '))
    }
  }
}
```

Ex:

```
> a(3)
[1] "1, 1"
[1] "1, 2"
[1] "1, 3"
[1] "2, 1"
[1] "2, 2"
[1] "2, 3"
[1] "3, 1"
[1] "3, 2"
[1] "3, 3"
>
```

Your code only prints the numbers on the left.

Comment: thank you very much!
if this works, then why the following code doesn't ?

#scan the numbers,identify the min ,save it as the first element of the output, repeat
Select <- function(n) {
  B <- rep(99,length(n)) #output array, same length as n
  repeat {
  for (j in 1:length(n)) {
    for (i in 1:length(n)) {
     if (all(n[i]<=n)) {B[j] <- n[i] #if n[i] is the smallest in the array, save it as B[j]
   n[i] <- Inf } #taking n[i] off the game
    
    }
  }
      if (all(n==Inf)) {return(B)} #if all are Inf then we're done, else... 
  } #repeat
 }

Comment: @EldanBinyamini Because `print(a, b)` only prints `a`. `print(a, b)` becomes `print(a)`. Separating by comma won't do anything.

Comment: (I tried to be as explainatory as possible)

I also added a picture since it's not copied correctly in here :

https://imgur.com/0a3vVO4

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write your function is using `expand.grid` over `l` lists of `seq`uences of length `l`.

```
f <- \(l) do.call(paste,
                  cbind(expand.grid(replicate(l - 1, seq.int(l), simplify=FALSE)), 
                        sep=', '))
f(3)
# [1] "1, 1" "2, 1" "3, 1" "1, 2" "2, 2" "3, 2" "1, 3" "2, 3" "3, 3"

f(4)
#  [1] "1, 1, 1" "2, 1, 1" "3, 1, 1" "4, 1, 1" "1, 2, 1" "2, 2, 1" "3, 2, 1"
#  [8] "4, 2, 1" "1, 3, 1" "2, 3, 1" "3, 3, 1" "4, 3, 1" "1, 4, 1" "2, 4, 1"
# [15] "3, 4, 1" "4, 4, 1" "1, 1, 2" "2, 1, 2" "3, 1, 2" "4, 1, 2" "1, 2, 2"
# [22] "2, 2, 2" "3, 2, 2" "4, 2, 2" "1, 3, 2" "2, 3, 2" "3, 3, 2" "4, 3, 2"
# [29] "1, 4, 2" "2, 4, 2" "3, 4, 2" "4, 4, 2" "1, 1, 3" "2, 1, 3" "3, 1, 3"
# [36] "4, 1, 3" "1, 2, 3" "2, 2, 3" "3, 2, 3" "4, 2, 3" "1, 3, 3" "2, 3, 3"
# [43] "3, 3, 3" "4, 3, 3" "1, 4, 3" "2, 4, 3" "3, 4, 3" "4, 4, 3" "1, 1, 4"
# [50] "2, 1, 4" "3, 1, 4" "4, 1, 4" "1, 2, 4" "2, 2, 4" "3, 2, 4" "4, 2, 4"
# [57] "1, 3, 4" "2, 3, 4" "3, 3, 4" "4, 3, 4" "1, 4, 4" "2, 4, 4" "3, 4, 4"
# [64] "4, 4, 4"
```

**Note:** `"R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"`.

Comment: unfortunately I can not use r functions such as expand.grid :/